# (nodeJS) Content-Type for S3 object: manually set to 'image/jpeg' but in S3 console comes up as 'application/octet'

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a JPEG buffer which uploads and downloads successfully from S3. However, I'm trying to send it over the Messenger API, and when it's accessed programmatically Messenger throws errors because according to the S3 console, the actual `Content-Type` of the image is `application/octet-stream`.

My manually entered metadata appears under `x-amz-meta-content-type`. According to the AWS documentation, this is the default behavior. How might I override it to get `image/jpeg` under `Content-Type`?

My code:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {
  Body: buffer,
  Bucket: <bucket>,
  Key: <key>,
  Metadata: {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
  }
};
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else  {
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't set it in the `Metadata` section, that's only for properties that will be prefixed with `x-amz-meta`. There is a `ContentType` parameter at the main level, like so:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {
  Body: buffer,
  Bucket: <bucket>,
  Key: <key>,
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
};
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else  {
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't catch that, super helpful, and simple fix.

Comment: After adding this.. i am not able to open images. is there any fix

Comment: @Yuvaraj since this solution works for other people, you should post your own question and provide the details of the exact issue you are experiencing, like what error code you get when you try to load an image from S3.

Comment: Sorry.. this solution works  as expected. in my case issue occured due to file corruption.